# Rails devise isn't saving the password upon registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I am using devise 4.8.1 with rails 7.0.3 and postgresql, I just started using devise, and I generated the views using `rails g devise:views` and then applied the migration using "rails db:migrate"

This is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :likes, foreign_key: 'author_id'

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :PostsCounter, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  def recent_posts
    posts.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
  end
end
```

This is the migration that I added:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

This morning devise was working fine, when I sign up the password gets encrypted and then saved now when I sign up and then try to login it says invalid email/password, when I checked my PostgreSQL database I found out that nothing is getting saved in the encrypted_password column [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxGyd.png), I tried searching online but couldn't find any solution, I also tried to reinstall the gems and nothing worked, I am not sure how to fix this issue, please assist me with this.

If you need any more information about my code please let me know.

Edit: I am not sure if it's okay to share this but this is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mirouhml/blog-rails-app/tree/feature/devise) and branch that has the issue (the issue is only presented in that branch feature/devise), I tried to share some pieces of the code I have but it's better to see the project structure in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating user from the rails console? If it gets saved with encrypted password, there is nothing wrong in the code. If it does not, it will throw the error and you can debug from there?

Comment: Hello, yes I did try creating it from the console, it works without issues, just using devise it's not working.

Comment: is the password encrypted while creating user from console? if that works then problem might be in ur views

Comment: Yes the password gets encrypted, which views should I share with you? I can share my GitHub repository as well (I'll edit my post and put it)